# how to load varchar value into decimal datatype in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I Have one doubt in sql server .
how to load data from one table to another table in sql server  when destination datatypes are differennt.
 i want load emplatlng values into [destemplatlng] table. here destination table lat and lng columns datatypes are decimal ,but in
the emplatlng table have varchar datatype.

```
table : [emplatlng]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[emplatlng](
    [pn_] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [lat] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lng] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'1', N'47.6864739', N' -117.416422
')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'2', N'47.6665465', N' -117.4166991
')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'3', N'47.629512', N' -117.241304
')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'5', N'47.6823378', N' -117.436788
')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'7', N'47.644277', N' -117.348362
')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'8', N'47.62510349999999', N' -117.5018943
')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'10', N'47.6564638', N' -117.4110428
')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'19', N'47.6693919', N' -117.4218557
')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'56', N'48.4249897', N' -119.5020331
')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[emplatlng] ([pn_], [lat], [lng]) VALUES (N'32', N'48.4249778', N' -119.5020466
')
GO

destination table : 
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[destemplatlng](
    [pn_] [varchar](80) NULL,
    [lat] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
    [lng] [decimal](9, 6) NULL
)
```

I treid like bellow :

```
insert into  destemplatlng
select pn_,convert( decimal(9,6),lat), convert( decimal(9,6),lng) from  emplatlng
```

its getting error like below : 
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server

Comment: -119.5020466 cannot fit in decimal (9,6)

Comment: @sepupic, that would be an artithmatic overflow error, but good spot too. I imagine the reason for the conversion error is because your  column `[lng]` begins with a white space, and has a Carriage Return/LineBreak at the end. Numbers don't contain either of those,

Comment: And 47.62510349999999 is worse. You should supply the correct type definition and onluy you knows how many digits your numbers can have. If you cannot fit in 38 digits use float

Comment: You can convert your LAT, but you cant convert your LNG because of spaces infront of it and that it has LineBreak. Remove those and you can convert it. And be aware of that a decimal(9,6) will cut of some of your decimals. - I justed tested it with removing your spaces and linebreaks, and it works perfectly.

Comment: @sepupic: we're talking latitude and longitude here; 8 decimal places already gives coordinates precise to the millimeter, and 6 is "merely" enough for precision close to a meter. The only problem here is the newlines in the constants.

Comment: compare and decide,declare @ii varchar(50)='47.62510349999999'
  select cast(@ii as decimal(18,14)),cast(@ii as float(53)),cast(@ii as NUMERIC(18,14)),
  cast(@ii as decimal(15,12))

Answer (score 1):

The problem is a couple things. like @sepupic said, your scale and accuracy is wrong for the data you've supplied. A `decimal(9,6)` will only store up to 6 decimal places, however, some of your numbers have more than that (for example `-117.5018943` has 7).

Also, you've started your numbers with whitespace, and ended them with a line break for your column `[lng]`. Numbers don't have these characters. You'll need to strip those out. This seems to work for the sample data we have (note I have had to recreate the destination table, due to the data type change):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[destemplatlng]([pn_] [varchar](80) NULL,
                                   [lat] decimal(15,12) NULL,
                                   [lng] decimal(15,12) NULL); 

GO
INSERT INTO destemplatlng
SELECT pn_,
       CONVERT(decimal(15,12),lat),
       CONVERT(decimal(15,12),REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(lng,N' ',N''),NCHAR(10),N''), NCHAR(13),N''))
FROM  emplatlng;
```

The obvious thing to learn from this is store your data in the correct datatype to start with. Don't store other data types as varchars; it just ends up causing more problems that it "solves".

Comment: You could also just LTRIM it instead of replaceing spaces with ''

Comment: @plaidDK You could, however, considering to OP has Line breaks at the end of the numbers as well, I thought best to use `REPLACE` across the board (as they might have data with white space in other "silly" places, like next to the decimal point).